# Compile Error: Argument Not Optional

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function:

```
Public Function getModuleAndEsnRange(fromSheetName As String, toSheetName As String, modulesColumn As Integer, firstModuleRow As Integer, esnsRow As Integer, firstEsnColumn As Integer) As String

    ...[code]...

    'returns the value
    getModuleAndEsnRange = moduleAndEsnRange

End Function
```

Elsewhere in the same module I call:

```
test = getModuleAndEsnRange(SHEET_WIP.Name, SHEET_WIP_DATA.Name, 1, 5, 3, 3)
```

And a box pops up that says "Compile Error: Argument Not Optional". It highlights in yellow the "Public Function getM... As String" and highlights in blue the "test = getM . . . 3, 3)"

What am I doing wrong? I have all 6 arguments listed when I call the function. . .

Comment: The error doesn't lie there. because if you remove the entire code in the function and then try `test = getModuleAndEsnRange(SHEET_WIP.Name, SHEET_WIP_DATA.Name, 1, 5, 3, 3)`, it will not give you an error. The error is somewhere else

Comment: Agreed - it may be helpful to see the code you removed for brevity: `...[code]...`

Comment: Turns out I had another function inside of the code I had not listed. The function inside the code did not have the appropriate matching arguments.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had another function inside of the code I had not listed. The function inside the code did not have the appropriate matching arguments.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `SHEET_WIP.Name` and `SHEET_WIP_DATA.Name` are string values.  It may be that one of them is `null`

Comment: How can a sheet name be null?